# Script Randomly Beginning to Error

Tags: powershell

Randomly, my script has begun erroring.

We changed JumpBox server, which I feel may be related, however i'm not sure.

The error is as followed:

```
You must provide a value expression on the right-hand side of the '-' operator.
At C:\Users\Timmsj\Desktop\Fixes\powershell\AD & Exchange New User Creation.ps1:128 char:26
+ $Folder = if ($SInitial - <<<< in 'a','b','c'){$AC}
+ CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExpectedValueExpression
```

The block in question is as followed:

```
$Folder = if ($SInitial -in 'a','b','c'){$AC}
      ElseIf ($SInitial -in 'd','e','f', 'g','h'){$DH}
      ElseIf ($SInitial -in 'i','j','k', 'l','m'){$IM}
      ElseIf ($SInitial -in 'n','o','p', 'q','r','s'){$NS}
      Else {$TZ}
```

**EDIT 1 - Full Code**

```
$GivenName = Read-Host -Prompt "What Is The New User's First Name?"
Write-Host " "

$Surname = Read-Host -Prompt "What Is The New User's Last Name?"
Write-Host " "

$Description = Read-Host -Prompt "What Is The Job Title & Department Of The New User? [Please format as Job Title – Dept]"
Write-Host " "


$DisplayName = $Surname + " " + $GivenName

$Mail = $GivenName + "." + $Surname + "@" + "royalberkshire.nhs.uk"

$MailAlias = $GivenName + "." + $Surname + "@" + $DNSRoot2

$SInitial = $Surname[0]
$Initial = $GivenName[0]
$SAMAccountName = $Surname + "" + $Initial
$SAMAccountLower = $SAMAccountName.ToLower()
$UserPrincipalName = $Surname+$Initial
$HD = "U"
$HDir = "\\RBHFILRED002\"
$AC = "Users_01$\"
$DH = "Users_02$\"
$IM = "Users_03$\"
$NS = "Users_04$\"
$TZ = "Users_05$\"

$Folder = if ($SInitial -in 'a','b','c'){$AC}
      ElseIf ($SInitial -in 'd','e','f', 'g','h'){$DH}
      ElseIf ($SInitial -in 'i','j','k', 'l','m'){$IM}
      ElseIf ($SInitial -in 'n','o','p', 'q','r','s'){$NS}
      Else {$TZ}

$group1 = "zz Everyone"
$group2 = "Safeboot Domain Users"

$defaultname = $SAMAccountName
$email = $GivenName + "." + $Surname
$i = 1
cls



While ((Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -eq '$SAMAccountName'" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -ne $null){
$SamAccountName = $defaultname + [string]$i 
$Mail = $email + [string]$i + "@" + "royalberkshire.nhs.uk"
$i++

}

$NewUserParams = @{
path                  = "OU=Users,OU=RBFT,DC=rbbh-tr,DC=nhs,DC=uk"
SamAccountName        = $SAMAccountName
Name                  = $SAMAccountName
DisplayName           = $DisplayName
GivenName             = $GivenName
Surname               = $Surname
EmailAddress          = $Mail
UserPrincipalName     = "$SAMAccountName@rbbh-tr.nhs.uk"
Title                 = $title
HomeDrive             = $HomeDrive
HomeDirectory         = "$HDir$Folder$SAMAccountName"
Description           = $Description
ChangePasswordAtLogon = $true
PasswordNeverExpires  = $false
AccountPassword       = $defpassword
Enabled               = $true
}

New-ADUser @NewUserParams -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $group1  -Members $SAMAccountName
Start-Sleep -s 10
Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $group2  -Members $SAMAccountName

cls
echo "Please Wait Whilst We Create The AD Account & Create The Exchange Mailbox.."
Start-Sleep -s 30

Enable-Mailbox -Identity $SAMAccountName
cls

echo "Please Wait Whilst We Activate The Exchange Mailbox..."
Start-Sleep -s 15
cls



echo "Username:" $SAMAccountName
Write-Host " "
echo "Password:" "Welcome123"
Write-Host " "
echo "Email:" $Mail
Write-Host " "
echo "Job Title - Department:" $Description
Write-Host " "
echo "Home Directory:" $HDir$Folder$SAMAccountName
Write-Host " "
```

Comment: I'd suspect an encoding issue with the script and the environment you are running the script in. Does it error all the time? On one machine? On all environments (console, ISE, VSCode, ...)?

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers Multiple Machines, everybody using it (10 people), On the new Jumpbox server that our boss built for us

Comment: Only sensible thing I can suggest is to cut the script in *(a working)* half on a session where the random error occurs and keep doing that until the script runs. Your latest deleted block of code is now suspect. Start adding from that block until it doesn't work anymore. Your latest addition is the culprit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you're seeing is what you'll get if you are running PowerShell 2.0.

```
PS[2] (1) > 1 -in 2,3,4,5
- : You must provide a value expression on the right-hand side of the '-' operator.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExpectedValueExpression
```

The `-in` operator was introduced in PowerShell 3.0 so look at the `$PSVersionTable` variable to see what version of PowerShell you are running. If you are stuck using 2.0, then you should use the `-contains` operator which is the reverse of `-in`

```
PS[2] (4) > 1,2,3,4,5 -contains 3
True
```

Comment: That would not account for the *Randomly begining to Error* but at least it's actionable and easy to check. I think the *random* wordchoice tripped us up :)

Comment: Asking a Powershell question only to ignore an answer from *the man* is badass :)

Comment: Apologies, will try this now. I was extremely ill, so was stuck in bed for a couple of days

Comment: Ended up just upgrading to PowerShell 4.0
Works fine now haha

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if a switch command with the `-Regex` parameter would catch the issue,
but it would allow to more easily create additional ranges and possibly pinpoint the problem.

The switch is wrapped in a small test script:

```
## Q:\Test\2018\06\19\SO_50925074.ps1
$AC,$DH,$IM,$NS,$TZ = 'AC','DH','IM','NS','TZ'

while ($True) {
    $SInitial = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter anything"

    $Folder = switch -regex ($SInitial) {
        '^[a-c]'    {$AC;Break}
        '^[d-h]'    {$DH;Break}
        '^[i-m]'    {$IM;Break}
        '^[n-s]'    {$NS;Break}
        '^[t-z]'    {$TZ;Break}
        '^[0-9]'    {"Number";Break}
        '^\p{L}'    {"Diacritique";Break}
        default     {"Other"}
    }

    "{0} Folder = {1}" -f $SInitial,$Folder
}
```

Sample output:

```
> Q:\Test\2018\06\19\SO_50925074.ps1
Enter anything: a
a Folder = AC
Enter anything: ö
ö Folder = Diacritique
Enter anything: ;
; Folder = Other
Enter anything: 7
7 Folder = Number
```

Comment: Does this do the same as the -in.

The reason it's set up this way, is because I need to set the user's homefolder based on their surname initial

Comment: Yes, simply try it out. The RegEx `^` anchors at the begin and the ranges in square brackets represent a class to match. I had to insert the break because the regular expression `\p{L}` matches all letters in all languages and would thus return an unwanted array result. A valuable resource to learn about [Regular Expressions](https://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html)

Comment: Did not work as intended. Just ended up repeating the Folder output, not actually doing as intended.

Comment: The switch does nothing different than your if..elseif..else returning a variable/text to $Folder. I don't know how you integrated it with your code. As per the test script it works here as expected.

Comment: I have added the full relevant script to the main post

Comment: Could it be that temporarily there was a scpace bewteen the minus sign and the `in` ?

Comment: I'm a bit confused, your title says randomly beginning to error - can't you nail it down to specific circumstances or does it happen always?